# JMeter - modify contents of jtl file

Tags: jmeter

While executing JMeter test cases through command line, system generates jtl file having following header :

`timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect`

I need results only for **timestamp, elapsed, label, responseCode**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the manual about [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) you should mark the properties as false except for the ones you want.

For example keep `jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true`

And change others as `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false`

Answer (score 0):

For once-only results obtaining you can run your test like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

If you need these changes to be permanent - add the following lines to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Useful JMeter Properties: Save Results. Save the World](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world)